# Create accordion IDs by looping an array in Jade/Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have an object array (components) and each of its objects has 2 attributes id and message. I would like to create accordion for each object like as follows:

```
.alert.alert-danger(style='background-color: #ff8080; color:white; width:70%')
  #headingOne.panel-heading(role='tab', style='text-align: left')
    h4.panel-title
      a(role='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapseOne', aria-expanded='true', aria-controls='collapseOne')
        i.more-less.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
        |                Title
  #collapseOne.panel-collapse.collapse(role='tabpanel', aria-labelledby='headingOne')
    .panel-body Content
```

where the id of each accordion is dynamic and is set from the object that I am iterating. I have verified that the object array has valid elements but could not get the IDs to be generated dynamically. Any help appreciated.

I got to this version and still it does not work. All I get on my NodeJS server is - internal error

```
#accordion.panel-group(role='tablist', aria-multiselectable='true', align='center')
  each item in [1,2,3]
    .alert.alert-danger(style='background-color: #ff8080; color:white; width:70%')
      #headingOne.panel-heading(role='tab', style='text-align: left')
        h4.panel-title
          a(role='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapse#{item}', aria-expanded='true', aria-controls='collapse#{item}')
            i.more-less.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
            |                   Title
      div(id="collapse#{item}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne")
          div(class="panel-body")
            !{item}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
href='#collapse#{item}'
```

Variables in string doesn't render anymore

If you are in Pug 2.0. Just change your code follow this way

```
href='#collapse'+item
```

I hope it will work well for you!